# get the diffrence array from 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some trouble to get the different array between 2 arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 107
        [CR_label] => f
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 121
        [CR_label] => C
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 0
    )

)
```

And my second array

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 107
        [CR_label] => f
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 117
        [CR_label] => B
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 121
        [CR_label] => C
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 0
    )

)
```

The result i wish to have is this :

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [CR_id] => 117
        [CR_label] => B
        [CR_question_id] => 54
        [CR_correct] => 0
    )
  )
```

I saw functions like array_diff but I don't know how to apply it there because it's a 2 dimensional arrays. Is there a proper way to do that in a recursive method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at any difference and not just one value:

```
$result = array_map('unserialize', array_diff(
    array_map('serialize', $array2), array_map('serialize', $array1)));

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_udiff()`](http://php.net/array_udiff), which allows you to define a custom comparison function:

```
array_udiff($array2, $array1, function(array $a, array $b) {
    return $b['CR_id'] - $a['CR_id'];
});
```

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: @AmalMurali Then the OP should explicitly specify it in his question.

Comment: @kingkero: Ah, you're right. I've removed my comment. (this one, too, will be removed after a while) +1

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `array_search` and `custom function`:

`Custom function:`

```
function arrayDiffDemensial(&$firstArray, &$secondArray) {
    $resultDiff= array();
    foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value) {
        if (array_search($value, $secondArray) === false) {
           $resultDiff[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $resultDiff;
}
```

`Your arrays:`

```
$firstArray= array(
    array('CR_id' => '107', 'CR_label'=> 'f', 'CR_question_id'=> 54, 'CR_correct'=> 1),
    array('CR_id' => '121', 'CR_label'=> 'C', 'CR_question_id'=> 54, 'CR_correct'=> 0),
);

$secondArray= array(
    array('CR_id' => '107', 'CR_label'=> 'f', 'CR_question_id'=> 54, 'CR_correct'=> 1),
    array('CR_id' => '117', 'CR_label'=> 'B', 'CR_question_id'=> 54, 'CR_correct'=> 0),
    array('CR_id' => '121', 'CR_label'=> 'C', 'CR_question_id'=> 54, 'CR_correct'=> 0),
);

$result = arrayDiffDemensial($secondArray , $firstArray);
var_dump($result);
```

**Result:**

```
 array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["CR_id"]=> string(3) "117" ["CR_label"]=> string(1) "B" ["CR_question_id"]=> int(54) ["CR_correct"]=> int(0) } }
```

Comment: What if I want to differentiate by more than one element of the arrays?

Comment: @kingkero Edited. Now it is ok